# Asynchronous Request (Order Matters)

Tags: asynchronous, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire` to execute a number of asynchronous requests concurrently, and `SwiftyJSON` to handle the response.

I need help making sure that appending to `moviesByCategory` occurs in order.

For example, the "top_rated" data response should be the first element appended to `moviesByCategory`, not "upcoming".

```
var moviesByCategory = [[JSON]]()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let apiEndPoints = ["top_rated", "popular", "now_playing", "upcoming"]
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for endPoint in apiEndPoints {
        let endPointURL = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(endPoint)?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1")!
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        getMoviesFromEndPoint(url: endPointURL)
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { 
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func getMoviesFromEndPoint(url: URL, group: dispatchGroup) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in
        if let data = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            self.moviesByCategory.append(json["results"].arrayValue)
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose for `DispatchGroup` is to reload the `UITableView` once all requests have completed.

Any help with this would be tremendously appreciated. Please do point out where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add a completion handler parameter to `getMoviesFromEndPoint`:

```
func getMoviesFromEndPoint(url: URL, completion: () -> Void) { ... }
```

and leave the group within after the network call completed:

```
getMoviesFromEndPoint(url: endPointURL) {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}
```

---

Complete code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let apiEndPoints = ["top_rated", "popular", "now_playing", "upcoming"]
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for endPoint in apiEndPoints {
        let endPointURL = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(endPoint)?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1")!
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        getMoviesFromEndPoint(url: endPointURL) {
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func getMoviesFromEndPoint(url: URL, completion: () -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in
        if let data = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            self.moviesByCategory.append(json["results"].arrayValue)                
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```